# Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade (from 11.10) removed all packages installed

Tags: 12.04, restore

I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 using a bootable USB. After the upgrade, all non-default packages from 11.10 are gone.

For example, I did not have Chromium, Eclipse etc. Although, I could see these in the history in the "Ubuntu Software Center".

Is there any way I can retrieve all these packages (even reverting back to 11.10 is also fine with me)?

What could be a possible reason for this (We plan to upgrade a few more machines)?

During the upgrade process, I had unchecked the box which asked permission to look online for upgrade/packages. Co

Comment: Look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/129117/system-very-slow-after-upgrading-to-12-04-using-unetbootin/129144#129144

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the sources.list has disabled the extension.
That is usual for upgrades as some of the apps may not be supported yet on the new release.
But from what i remember Chromium and Eclipse should not require there packages as they come added in ubuntu repos.

Check out here : vi /etc/apt/sources.list
if you have the packages that you require.

The best option would be to find the package for 12.04 and use those.

Comment: Thanks for the help, stevoo! I don't see the list of packages in the file you mentioned.

But, I have anyway installed the needed packages manually and am good again :-). Though, it wasted about 2 hours of time unnecessarily.

Thanks again!