# System very slow after upgrading to 12.04 using Unetbootin

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I downloaded the 12.04 and used Unetbootin. Then when I tried to install, it asked whether to upgrade, so I upgraded (from 10.04). I think it didn't format my file system, as some of the apps are intact. But I doubt, if the installation has taken more space in addition to previous 10.04.

But now, after upgrade, loading apps have become very slow and also when I browse the youtube, the video and audio isn't smooth. I feel the upgrade has bloated my system.

Any solutions pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any operating system for any time upgrading from older version did not worked well for me. I always advice clean install. It is more easy to install your previous applications and restore your application specific files instead of cope with numerous errors after an upgrade. I have witnessed lots of unsuccessful Ubuntu upgrade attempts before and my advice is "Do not upgrade!".