# Some applications is not working after upgrading from Ubuntu 11.04 32 bit to Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, installation, upgrade, data-recovery

I updated my system from Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit to Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit using installation DVD. I used option 'update older installation of Ubuntu 11.10'. Now my softwares and settings pre-installed before update are not recovered within Update setup. They are still stored on my hard disk but I can't use them as I used to earlier. How can I recover my older installed softwares and settings.

Comment: You might as well just start over as you can't jump from 32 bit to 64 bit.... never have and never will be able to, they are two completely different architectures...

Comment: Look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129117/system-very-slow-after-upgrading-to-12-04-using-unetbootin/129144#129144

Comment: So now if I can't jump from 32bit to 64bit architectures, I wish to delete previously installed softwares and settings. Where can I find my previously installed softwares and settings to delete them to clear disk space?

Comment: I've asked a separate question inspired by your slightly unusual approach: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192980/switching-from-32-to-64-bit-via-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore your old applications for these reasons:

1. You changed your architecture from; this will make your old applications useless.
2. Some of the old applications maybe not supported anymore in Ubuntu 12.04, so some of them may be lost.

You will have to install your favorite applications again.