# Upgrade from 10.10 cannot be done

Tags: upgrade

I still have 10.10 running. I would like to upgrade. If I do it, I get "Not supported" messages.

What can I do?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.10 is EOL ; so it's better to download and install a fresh ISO of Ubuntu.

There are major changes in Ubuntu, so it's beter to work from scratch than to upgrade from 10.10

Please advise you first about the hardware specifications required for Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 it could be possible your computer has a hard time running Ubuntu 12.xx

[information on upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)
(This link I give you on how to, but as said before: it's more advisable to do a fresh install (personal experience) )

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @joris-donders. Upgrading is an ugly process which leaves you with numerous problems to dealt with. Please look at the question and my answer to it here:
[System very slow after upgrading to 12.04 using Unetbootin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129117/system-very-slow-after-upgrading-to-12-04-using-unetbootin/129144#129144)